# Java cript fs write

Tags: json, node.js

Всем привет. 
Мучаюсь уже сколько времени, но не могу никак сделать переписать этот код и сделать его асинхронным...

Если кто то знает, как это сделать, подскажите пожалуйста, безумно буду благодарен[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

P.s. извиняюсь, что скрином отправил код. Не получилось текстом.

Comment: Дубль https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/963091/190728